# Prerequisites for Creating Chrome/Safari Extensions

Tags: javascript

I have been a programmer for a long time now but have majorly operated in C and Fortran. I like to believe I am good at scientific/numerical computing.

Recently, I had an idea for a browser extension. I did some googling and realized that Javascript is my best option to do so. I have never in my life looked at HTML or Javascript or CSS. The Safari and Chrome websites suggest that I should learn HTML, CSS and Javascript.

My question was- how should I proceed with this goal in mind. I don't plan to make web applications anytime but want to concentrate only on browser extensions. How much of HTML and CSS do I really need to know? Will the [Web Fundamentals at CodeAcademy](http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/web) suffice? Do I need to get that out of the way before attempting to study Javascript? How should I plan this study?

P.S. I looked at a few books on Javascript and it looks eerily close to C which is a big plus for me. Learning Javascript isn't my concern, learning HTML/CSS is.

Comment: I think http://eloquentjavascript.net/contents.html should teach you everything you need to know (or at least to get the big picture)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Code Academy Web Fundamentals link should suffice for the HTML & CSS. Don't be afraid of HTML- you're just marking up, or rather describing the presentation of, a document. With CSS, for the most part, you're just declaring styles on the document: Make this paragraph bold; Change this background to red, etc.

I am still learning JavaScript but I bet It'll be easier for you because of your background in C. The syntax should look very familiar. Perhaps one of the most obvious differences is that C needs a compiler to run whereas JavaScript just runs in your browser.

Some nice sandboxes to try out snippets of code are http://www.jsfiddle.net and http://www.jsbin.com.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.codecademy.com/ is a great place to start.

If you want a nice technical guide to the DOM, JS, the server, and really the web in general, [this is also a good guide](http://taligarsiel.com/Projects/howbrowserswork1.htm)